# How to select fields from one table and order them by fields from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables.

Structure of first table:

```
id
secondtableid
value
```

Structure of second table:

```
id
title
```

How can I select fields 'id' from first table know value of 'value' column and order result by value of 'title' column of second table, if secondtable id is id of second table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:)

```
select id from first_table 
inner join second_table on first_table.secondtableid = second_table.id
where value = 'Known Value'
order by second_table.title
```

Answer (score 2):

You can order by fields you don't select.

```
select FirstTable.id, FirstTable.value
    from FirstTable
        inner join SecondTable on (FirstTable.SecondTableID=SecondTable.ID)
    order by SecondTable.Title
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select 
    firsttable.id, firsttable.value, secondtable.title 
from
    firsttable 
join
    secondtable on firsttable.secondtableid = secondtable.id 
order by 
    secondtable.title
```

Comment: `JOIN secondtable ON firsttable.secondtableid = secondtable.id`

Answer (score -1):

This a beginner question, so I will answer as simple as possible:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.value
FROM       table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.secondtableid = t2.id 
ORDER BY t2.title
```

You can `JOIN` the tables, indicating how they join.

Comment: I agree.  The original answer was missing a couple pieces, but constructive criticism would have been a more appropriate response.

Comment: And, also, I believe in giving OP the general lines (in this case, `JOIN` is what OP needed to learn) not the "strict-as-I-asked-or-else-will-be-downvoted" answer. This is why I'm starting to give up on answering all-too-easy questions. Newbie "answerers" are too competitive. :)